# Transcribe this short audio clip for me please (Canadian French)

Tags: grammaire, québec

Transcribe only the French part, please. It's only a few seconds long.

Link: [audio clip](http://vocaroo.com/i/s16p30TS1JE8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man in question said in French language:

> Comme disait [Yogi Berra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra): *"Ce n'est pas fini tant que la partie n'est pas
>   terminée"*

Which thing means:

> As [Yogi Berra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra) said: *"It ain't over till it's over"*

Comment: Are you really sure about the last part, right after "ce n'est pas fini tant"? What I hear sounds more like this: "la partine potarmine". But I don't know what that means, let alone how to spell it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there exists a standard way to say that quote in French. I do not doubt that. I'm simply asking what exactly the guy is saying. He obviously is not quoting it word for word. Listen again, please. it absolutely does not sound anything like "ce n'est pas fini." The words are different. Can't you hear that?

Comment: No problem. Thank you.

Comment: @user69786 I agree with the current transcription (and I think that the Prime Minister in question is probably Jean Chrétien).

Comment: @ChrisW Very likely, since that clip seems to be in the context of the vote for Quebec separation, which looked like it would be successful and Jean Chretien (Canadian Prime Minister at the time, who was against separation) commented about how it wasn't over until it was over. Turns out he was right. I also agree with the transcription.

Comment: Quebec separatism has been a long-standing (even on-going) issue, but I think that I recognize his voice, and his way of saying things. I don't think it's Paul Martin or Trudeau.